# How to retain history for the hive command line interpreter

Tags: hive

It seems that each time I restart the hive command line (*cli*) the history file `~/.hivehistory` were overwritten. What might be done to retain the history for the hive interpreter between sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had multiple `hive` sessions open concurrently. It would be nice to know if there were a way for them to **append** their results to the `.hivehistory` - instead of overwriting each other.

Answer (score 0):

I use Hive3.1.2,.hiveHistory were not overwritten.

Comment: Pls see my answer.  You should specify if you were running multiple hive sessions concurrently; otherwise, there is no evidence you have addressed the problem already identified.

Comment: Oh, I didn't look carefully.I think you should modify the question by adding this condition.

Comment: I'll delete this answer later.